# Magento image uploader in Admin product page doesn't work

Tags: magento, admin, uploading, image-upload

All the permissions are correct and the php.ini is fixed, and there's no problem with SSL or secure admin interface but it still won't upload.

I click on a product, go to the Image section, select an image to upload and it appears to upload. However, the image doesn't appear in the list of product images and then I get kicked back out to the login page!

Comment: Please turn on logging and post the contents of your var/log/exception.log and any other relevant information help track this error down.  Does it only affect product images, or category and CMS pages too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get the built-in Flash uploader playing nicely with our production server, even though it worked fine in the development environment... but I replaced it with this extension and uploads work fine now: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Tobias+Renger/extension/1756/no-flash-uploader

Comment: Yep that worked. It's funny how this problem was solved by getting rid of Flash..

Answer (score 3):

The only experience I've had with the uploader not working was mysteriously to do with the base URL domain not matching either the link, skin, media or javascript URL domain as specified in System > Configuration > Web.

I didn't investigate further, it is probably something to do with cookie origin policies which you cannot do much about. All you can do is check they all match for at least the default config, individual stores won't affect the admin URLs.

Comment: I think I'm seeing a similar situation at the moment, did you find a resolution?

Comment: @Jonathan - As I recall I made sure the domains matched and left it at that. I also remember looking at the uploader's source in `lib/flex/` but I've only done actionscript once before so couldn't really find a solution. Since the source is there it is possible you could write a fix for it and recompile the SWF.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your flash version is up-to-date and enabled in your browser.